# Alternative to Guava Service in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, service, guava

I'm currently porting a library from Java to .NET. I find that one of the classes is a [Guava Service](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ServiceExplained), (particularly, an `AbstractExecutionThreadService`). I'm trying to look for what would be the recommended alternative in .NET, but I can't find anything.

Is there an accepted alternative, or should I create my custom implementation of Guava Services?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think we need to have corresponding library in .Net because Guava is trying to solve mainly things for Java developers. Some of those things might not be a problem for .Net programmers. Better needs to understand the situation in Java and find corresponding mechanism in .Net. If needs to be done fast just create coresponding classes in .Net and get things compiled. Later correct else you will end up in creating Guava lib for .Net